# Predictive model with time-dependent predictors

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, missing-data, time-varying-covariate

I am working on a project to predict whether undergraduate students will return for their 2nd semester. I would like to make initial predictions for incoming students based on predictor data available at the start of their first semester, and update these predictions daily throughout the semester as new predictor data become available. I am struggling with how to deal with time in this situation, as my data and problem don't seem to fit other frameworks I'm aware of for dealing with time-varying data (e.g., time series, survival models, incremental/online learning).

To sum up my data:

- The outcome is a binary variable (returned for 2nd semester or not) that is not known until the start of the second semester.
- The predictor variables may be time-invariant or change through time in different ways:
- some variables are known at the start of the semester and never change (e.g., high school GPA)
- some variables are known at the start of the semester but may change one or more times (e.g., major)
- some variables are unknown at the start of the semester and become available at a later date (e.g., mid-term grades)
- some variables represent events that may occur one or more times at any point in the semester (e.g., room change, academic alert)
- The effects of the predictors may be time-dependent. For example, having 3 academic alerts through day 5 of the semester may be a stronger indicator of not being retained than having 3 academic alerts through day 100 of the semester.

I would like to find a good approach for making predictions at multiple time points (i.e., days) through the semester as the predictors change. I've considered the following approaches:

1. Fit a separate model using a separate training dataset for each time point. For example, there would be a "Day 0" model that makes predictions based on all data available at the start of the semester, a "Day 5" model that makes predictions based on all data available through the fifth day of the semester, etc.
2. Fit a single model using a "long" training dataset that contains one row per student per day. "Day" would be included as a predictor, allowing interactions between "day" and the other predictors to account for time-dependent effects. One issue with this approach is that there would be many missing values in the training set for variables that are not available at the start of the semester. For example, if mid-term grades are available at day 50, values would be missing data for all rows where day < 50.
3. Fit a single model with a "wide" training dataset that contains one row per student and multiple date-specific variables for each time-dependent predictor. For example, for academic alerts, there could be separate variables for the count of alerts for days 1-7, days 8-14, days 15-21, etc. One issue with this approach is that when making predictions early in the semester, many of these variables would still be unknown (for example, "academic alerts days 8-14" would not be known on day 1 of the semester), so there would be many missing values in the data used for prediction.

Do any of these approaches seem reasonable? Are there existing modeling frameworks for dealing with this kind of problem?